# Disable scroll when push over menu (off-canvas) is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, off-canvas-menu

I'm building a off-canvas push menu and everything is working, there are a few aspects I can't seem to figure out.

1. How to disable the scrolling of the content-wrapper.
2. How to only scroll the off canvas menu. Right now it scrolls the height of the website itself.

Here is a code pen to show you what issues I'm running into.

[code pen demo](http://codepen.io/icekomo/pen/LNwEWM)

HTML

```
    <div id="menu">
    <h1>This is the push over menu</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus alias id accusantium, consequatur, repellendus iure impedit consectetur aspernatur quas quo. Doloremque, facere autem ex tempora dicta consequuntur, possimus minima natus.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quis voluptatibus, nesciunt debitis ea ullam consectetur illo cum odit nobis explicabo cumque, vitae quia dolores, fugit maxime ad nisi earum.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus voluptatibus dignissimos possimus, voluptatem ducimus illum voluptate deleniti et culpa autem laboriosam, pariatur voluptates enim facilis, animi nesciunt dolor expedita repellat.</p>
</div>

<div id="burger-icon">
    <h2>burger menu</h2>
</div>

<div id="content-wrapper">
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum ullam, alias dignissimos dolore, a ratione dicta ipsam delectus facilis quod voluptates autem beatae sed impedit eligendi, consequuntur necessitatibus modi nemo?</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  background-color:red;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#burger-icon {
  position:fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2000;
}

#content-wrapper {
  padding-top: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

JS

```
    var isOpen = false;

// sets the about off screen number
var aboutOffPosition = $("#menu").css("left");

//console.log($("#about").css("left"));

function openMenu() {
    // console.log("burger clicked");

    if(isOpen === false)
    {

        // slide over the about section
        TweenMax.to($("#menu"),".75", {left:0, ease: Power1.easeIn});

        // move over the content
        TweenMax.to($("#content-wrapper"),1, {x:500, ease: Power1.easeIn});

        isOpen = true;
    }
    else{

        // slide back the about section
        TweenMax.to($("#menu"),".75", {left:aboutOffPosition, ease: Power1.easeIn});

        // move back the content
        TweenMax.to($("#content-wrapper"),".5", {x:0, ease: Power1.easeIn});

        isOpen = false;
    }
}

// burger icon
$('#burger-icon').click(openMenu);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you want to disable scroll of content-wrapper when menu is open and at the same time scroll should be enable for menu.

you just need to remove min-height from the #content-wrapper and set overflow to hidden to hide the scroll.

```
#content-wrapper {
 padding-top: 40px;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  background-color:red;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: the min height was created to simulate the issue that I am having on the production files. The content of the website is much longer then the content of the slide on menu.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding a container(.app) around the content and applying this css to the project.

```
    body {
  // scroll fix
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  // end scroll fix
}
.app {
  // scroll fix
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  // end scroll fix
}

#about {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I updated the codepen to reflect these changes.